# Crear usuario con permisos de root para poder descargar archivos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, debian-9, ubuntu-server

Tengo montada esta estructura en un servidor linux con Debian.

```
/root/backups/mysql
```

Dentro de este directorio hay carpetas con las diferentes copias de la BD del propio sistema.

Cuando creé el usuario de sistema en este servidor remoto me dieron un "usuario" llamado **debian** que si ejecuto el comando "sudo su" puedo acceder a la carpeta root.

Pero yo lo que necesito es un usuario que pertenezca a root para poder descargar archivos en remoto como os explico después.

Para ello he hecho lo siguiente

> adduser edutest
>
> usermod -aG sudo edutest

Una vez hecho esto, si me loggeo por ssh con dicho usuario y hago un "sudo su" puedo acceder a la carpeta "/root" que es donde quiero acceder. (Hasta aquí todo funciona bien)

El problema lo tengo aquí, estoy intentando conectar desde mi máquina local (windows) al servidor en remoto para descargarme un archivo, para ello hago el siguiente comando

> scp -r edutest@85.xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/backups/mysql c:\tmp\

El error que me da, es un Access denied, ja que accedo como "edutest" pero me faltaria hacer el sudo su.

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Si, de una no toma los permisos `su` debería abrir primero un canal ssh y posterior a esto otorgar los permisos `su`, como sugerencia debería mover los archivos a un path donde el usuario `edutest` tenga accesos de lectura sin necesidad de otrogar permisos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren varias opciones; al menos tres.

### Mueve a otro lugar esa carpeta.

Como el directorio `/root/` tiene únicamente permisos de lectura para el usuario `root` y para nadie más, no puedes copiar sin ser este usuario (poco importan los permisos de lectura en cada subdirectorio o archivo: no pueden ser listados). Por lo que podrías mover la carpeta `/root/backups/` a otro lugar, digamos, a `/var/tmp` con:

```
mv -r /root/backups/ /var/tmp
```

y ya podrías copiar con:

```
scp -r edutest@85.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/tmp/backups/mysql ...
```

### Usar `sudo` y luego `tar` pero sin `scp` sino con `ssh`.

Te voy a pasar un secreto que vale oro:

```
ssh edutest@85.xxx.xxx.xxx 'sudo tar cz /root/backups' | tar xz --strip-components=1 -C <ruta_de_la_carpeta>
```

Lo que hago es pasar un comando a través del cliente de `ssh`. Supongo que el usuario `edutest` pertenece a `sudo` (como mostraste en tu pregunta), y comprimo el archivo `/root/backups` con tar, todo desde la línea de comandos. En lugar de guardarlo en un archivo lo paso directamente al *stdout* que será recibido con otro `tar` pero ahora lo extraerá a la carpeta con la ruta que desees después del parámetro `-C`. Ese es un truco útil, pero otro truco todavía más útil es el parámetro `--strip-components`. Este parámetro indica a `tar` que borre los componentes de los nombres de los archivos durante su extracción. Es decir, si le pido que elimine el `/root` de `/root/backups`, le estoy pidiendo que elimine 1, entonces es `--strip-components=1`, por lo que se extraerá la carpeta `backups`. Puedo aumentar los componentes a eliminar digamos, hasta quedar sólo `mysql` y su contenido.

Esto último (para que sólo quede la carpeta `mysql` sin `/root/backup`) sería con `--strip-components=2`, es decir:

```
ssh edutest@85.xxx.xxx.xxx 'sudo tar cz /root/backups' | tar xz --strip-components=2 -C <ruta_de_la_carpeta>
```

### Permitiendo la conexión con el usuario root.

Esta opción no es tan segura, pero si es lo suficientemente segura si se hace con cuidado.

1. Habilitar la conexión al usuario root por ssh.

Esto se hace editando el archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` en el campo `PermitRootLogin` tiene que quedar con el valor `yes`, es decir `PermitRootLogin yes`.

Lo puedes hacer con tu editor de código preferido: vim, emacs, nano, pico, ed, sublime, gedit, notepad++, atom, visual studio, pero con `sudo`.

Otra forma de editarlo en una sóla linea (y dejando un respaldo con el mismo nombre pero la extensión ".bak") es con `sed`:

```
sudo sed -ri.bak 's/^(PermitRootLogin )(.*)/\1yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

En caso de que quieras usar una contraseña para acceder al usuario root (algo que no es recomendable pero igual se puede hacer), sería con algo análogo:

```
sudo sed -ri.bak 's/^(PasswordAuthentication )(.*)/\1yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

2. Reiniciar el servidor ssh para que las modificaciones se muestren.

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```
3. Adecuar las llaves permitidas para ingresar al usuario root (En caso de que uses un par de llaves, lo cual es algo altamente recomendado).

Si por lo general ingresas a tu usuario edutest con un par de llaves. Las llaves autorizadas están en el archivo `~/edutest/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Entonces copias aquel contenido al archivo `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, por ejemplo, con `cat ~/edutest/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Si no existe el archivo `.ssh` en la carpeta `/root`, entonces lo creas con mkdir. Si no existe tampoco el archivo `authorized_keys`, puedes copiarlo con:

```
cp {~edutest,~root}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Y luego modificar los permisos:

```
chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod u=rw /root/.ssh/authorized_keys # Como recomienda authorized_keys(5)
```

En ese archivo deberá estar tu **clave pública**.

4. Ahora ya puedes copiar de forma remota con el usuario `root`.

   ```
   scp -r root@85.xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/backups/mysql ...
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por una respuesta tan completa. 1000 gracias